# pythonocc identify holes (and it dimension) in surface

Tags: surface, identify, pythonocc

I have an object, and I am checking it's faces (for exmaple the attached object).
First I have checked if each of it's faces is a plane/cylinder or Bspline surface.
Now, I need to check  if the face has holes in it (it can have cylindrical or square of any other hole) and to get the dimensions of this hole.

With what functions in pythonocc library , I can detect that? please advice

see attached image as an example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCqsH.png)

Zofit

Comment: You need to revise your grammar as it's kind of difficult to follow you. Also, you should try to add some example of the output you expect and a snippet code if possible.

Comment: I am adding here an example of the the object I am investigating